# How can a symbol table be designed to support function overloading?

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-construction

I'm creating a compiler and really struggling with the semantic analysis phase. I'm not sure how to deal with function overloading in a symbol table. I can't seem to find any resources that describe this particular problem. I think that name mangling must be used somewhere and I'm pretty sure that types from the AST should be converted to strings.

Multiple functions with the same name are allowed to be declared in the same scope as long as each declaration has a different set of parameters. The following snippet is an example in my language (it's quite similar to Swift).

```swift
func add(a: Int, b: Int) {
  return a + b;
}
func add(a: Float, b: Float) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I don't know how to store functions in the symbol table. This is part of my symbol table data structure.

```cpp
struct Symbol {};

struct Var final : Symbol {
  std::string type;
};

using FuncParams = std::vector<std::string>;
struct Func final : Symbol {
  std::string ret;
  FuncParams params;
};

using Table = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Symbol>>;
struct Scope {
  Table table;
  Scope *parent = nullptr;
};
using Scopes = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Scope>>;
```

I could use a `std::unordered_multimap` and store the function name `add` as the key and store the names of the parameters in the symbol object. I could use a `std::unordered_map` and store the function name decorated with the parameters `add_Int_Int` as the key and store the names of the parameters in the symbol object as well.

Also, should `Symbol` be a base class or should I put all kinds of symbols in the one `Symbol` object? I've seen many examples of using an `enum` to differentiate between functions, variables and type declarations but a function stores return type and parameter types. Should I use a tagged union?

I feel like there's a smart and simple way of solving this but I just can't find it.

**Update:**

I've taken a suggestion from @NeilButterworth and used unmangled function names as the symbol keys and this seems to be the way to go (but what do I know!). Answers to my other questions or some advice on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how C++ does it? There might be other ways, but the C++ [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) is relatively simple. There are other ways as well, and there are probably quite a few research papers (both freely available and paid for) about this issue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you elaborate? Consider this function `func f(n: Float) {}` and this call: `f(5)`. If I lookup `f_Int` in the symbol table at the call site, I won't find anything. I want to find `f_Float` and then look for conversions from `Int` to `Float`.

Comment: You don't want name mangling here - look up the named functions without respect to parameters, and then walk the list looking for ones that match parameters or for which there is a conversion

Comment: @NeilButterworth I was beginning to come to that conclusion myself. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to do what @NeilButtworth said in the comments. But you will want to build some logic around creating "compatible" type trees. Becuase you want a function to have parameters that are compatible. I would recommend some function that returns if a type is a child of another type like `isTypeCompatible(actualType,formalType)`. Then from there you can try and find the function that has the most *specific* signature that matches the call. So `f(5)` should call `f(int)` since 5 is an explicit int but only an implicit float. One way of doing this is by seeing which signature minimizes the distance up a type tree from the given types and the formal types.

EDIT: By "compatible" type trees it essentially the same as inheritance. Like how if we have g(float) `g(5)` works since an int literal is convertible to a float literal. The type trees are much easier to construct with custom user classes since you AST should already construct upon parsing and type checking.